Get name (nameof) of class properties with data from instance of that class
I want to get the names of properties (members?) of a class inside another class and the data stored in an instance of that class. Any help would be appreciated!
Eg:
public class GpioData
{
    public bool pin_mosi_toGnd = false; //1=Fault, 0=NoFault
    public bool pin_mosi_toVdd = false; //1=Fault, 0=NoFault
}
public class DutTestdata
{
    public GpioData gpioData = new GpioData();
    public SpiData spiData = new SpiData();
}

in code:
DutTestdata dutTestData = new DutTestdata();
dutTestData.gpioData.pin_mosi_toGnd = false;

Requested output:
"gpioData.pin_mosi_toGnd = false"
or
"dutTestData.gpioData.pin_mosi_toGnd = false"
There are a lot of variables so I'd rather not make strings of every variable.

Edit (hopefully more clear now)


I would like to iterate through all properties of the classes and
'print' the actual value (true/false, measured voltage etc.) together with
the name of the properties.

public class GpioData
{
    private UInt32 _BitsAll = 0;

    private bool _pin_mosi_toGnd = false; //1=Fault, 0=NoFault
    private bool _pin_mosi_toVdd = false; //1=Fault, 0=NoFault
 
    public bool pin_mosi_toGnd { get { return _pin_mosi_toGnd; } set { _pin_mosi_toGnd = value; } }
    public bool pin_mosi_toVdd { get { return _pin_mosi_toVdd; } set { _pin_mosi_toVdd = value; } }

    public UInt32 BitsAll
    {
        get { return _BitsAll; }
        set
        {
            _BitsAll = value;

            _pin_mosi_toGnd = (value & 0x0010) > 0 ? true : false;
            _pin_mosi_toVdd = (value & 0x0020) > 0 ? true : false;
            
        }
    }
}

public class DutTestdata
{
    private GpioData _gpioData = new GpioData() { BitsAll = 0 };

    public GpioData gpioData { get { return _gpioData; } set { _gpioData = value; } }

    public DutTestdata() { }
    /// <summary>
    /// Fill bitfields from rcvd data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="status">Global status bits recvd [uint32]</param>
    //public void Testdata(UInt32 data, TestData index)
    public void Testdata(byte[] data, TestData index)
    {
        switch (index)
        {
            case TestData.GPIO_BITS:
                _gpioData.BitsAll = funcs.ByteArrayToUint32(data);
                break;
        }
    }
}

DutTestdata dutTestData = new DutTestdata();
dutTestData.gpioData.pin_mosi_toGnd = false;
or
dutTestdata.Testdata(<Data>, <Index>); //Give Recvd data + index

Desired output string(for textfile) eg:
gpioData.pin_mosi_toGnd = false
or
GpioData.pin_mosi_toGnd = false
or
dutTestData.gpioData.pin_mosi_toGnd = false 
(etc.)

Some examples would be well appreciated.

Side note: a "member" is anything that is part of a type: properties, fields, constructors, methods, etc. And what you have are fields, not properties.

So, you want to set all bool properties in dutTestdata.gpioData set to false without having to type dutTestData.gpioData.pin_mosi_toXXX = false for each in source code?

so essentially you want to print the entire content of your data-structures, like serializing?

$"{nameof(DutTestdata.gpioData)}.{nameof(GpioData.pin_mosi_toGnd)} = {dutTestData.gpioData.pin_mosi_toGnd}". The easiest way to accomplish this is to override ToString in the classes.

Or, easier but not exactly the same format. https://dotnetfiddle.net/tp6i5p ... to make your desired format, use reflection to make your own "serializer"

^^ If you do, mind that runtime-reflection is quite costly and you may want to opt for source generation if that's a k.o.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes I noticed the "because you used fields, not properties :(" in the 'fiddle'. I changed the fields to properties (not done yet, it's a lot of refactoring), because its good practice (not sure why I didn't...). Does this make the serializing/reflection easier? Could you provide an example?

Note that the fiddle was not mine. Reflection works with fields and properties as well. For serialization, it depends on the framework used. The one used in the fiddle apparently works with both just by setting an option. Binding (e.g. WinForms data binding) works only with properties. Note that nameof() is purely a static compile-time thing, while reflection is dynamic.

Some examples would be well appreciated.
